# Two panel layout in java (first panel has fix size, second has remainder size)

Tags: java, layout, jpanel, layout-manager

I want some like this:

[image: JPanel_Layout.png]

How make it ideologically correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your requirement seems to be a relatively simple use of BorderLayout.

The code snippet below assumes the panel are being added to a JFrame. Hence the getContentPane() calls.

```
javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();

jPanel1.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 32767));
jPanel1.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 100));
jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(60, 300));

getContentPane().add(jPanel1, java.awt.BorderLayout.WEST);

getContentPane().add(jPanel2, java.awt.BorderLayout.EAST);
```

Specify the maximum, minimum and preferred width of jPanel1 to be 60 px. Leave JPanel2 to "float".

If separation of the panes is required add a third pane of fixed width (say 5 px)

```
getContentPane().add(jPanel3, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
```